# Google Calendar API - Displaying a list of people who are out of office?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am working on creating a board for work which will use the Google Calendar API to display a list of people who are marked "OOO" (out of office). All the resources I've found regarding the Google Calendar API, so far, appear to be for entering data into a calendar instead of display info from a calendar.

I guess I am just wondering if the API is capable of doing what I would like it to do and if there are any resources I should be looking at to get started.

Comment: There is no direct way to get list of people who is OOO with calendar API. Work around would be getting event using even.list and write your own query to check the event description is "OOO". This works only when you have access to all the users who all are OOO and in the description they mentioned "OOO".

Comment: I figured it would be something like that, thanks!